Completing simpledialog.askstring boots cursor back to command line instead of main window
I'm creating a choose your own adventure, and I have it set so that a user can enter a keyword to return to a specific choice.  So when the game starts, it has 2 simpledialog.askstring() questions, one to ask if you've played before (to skip the intro), and one to ask if you want to use a keyword.  The problem is, once you complete one or both of these simpledialog windows, sometimes the main window ends up behind the command line, and the cursor/focus is either nowhere or in the command line.  I want it to put the cursor into the entry widget as soon as the dialogues are closed.
This snippet has the same problem:
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import simpledialog
from tkinter import scrolledtext

class Game:

    def __init__(self, root):

        self.root = root
        self.root.title("Game Window")
        self.entry_widget = tk.Entry(root)
        self.entry_widget.pack()
        self.scrollbox = scrolledtext.ScrolledText(root, width=40, height=10)
        self.scrollbox.pack()

        self.on_open()

    def on_open(self):

        response = simpledialog.askstring("Question", "Have you played before?")
        if response is not None:
            if response.lower() == "no":
                self.scrollbox.insert(tk.END, "Welcome!\n")
            elif response.lower() == "yes":
                self.scrollbox.insert(tk.END, "Let's play!\n")

root = tk.Tk()
app = Game(root)
root.mainloop()

I have tried using focus_set() to bring the focus back to the main window in several ways:
self.entry.focus_set()

self.root.focus_set()

and
self.entry.focus_set()
self.root.lift()
self.root.focus_force()

None of these seemed to make any difference.
Googling got me to this answer: link
But it didn't seem quite right, and when I tried the solutions there, it didn't work.

Please create a [mcve].  Also, do you call mainloop anywhere in your code?

When I use self.entry_widget.focus_force() it works for me.....not sure why you are using self.entry when you named it self.entry_widget

@Rory that worked perfectly, thanks.  I had it as just "entry" in my original code, which the smaller examples are from. I don't know why I named it "entry_widget" in my example X-D  Thanks again.  I was so close, but so far, lol.
